# Seemed to be in “(no branch)” and then lost my changes

Tags: git

I was trying to push from my Git workspace up to Github but my added and committed changes didn't seem to get uploaded.

Then, doing a "git branch" I got something that looked like this :

```
git branch
* (no branch)
  master
```

Foolishly, I thought I could get back into master with

```
git checkout master
```

and now my changes seem to have gone. My master branch is about three days old. And there seems no way to switch back to this (no branch).

I checked this question [Git : seemed to be in “(no branch)” and then lost my changes](https://serverfault.com/questions/56722/git-seemed-to-be-in-no-branch-and-then-lost-my-changes) where answers suggest to do a `git reflog show`followed by a checkout. I tried that and I got this:

```
$ git reflog
    0f27ae7 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from HEAD to master
    7b8ee7b HEAD@{2}: commit: 14/05/2017 3:33pm
    ff60409 HEAD@{3}: commit: 14/05/2017 3:33pm
    0f27ae7 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to 0f27ae7236aabbe8cccfba82e201e36368a05054
    0f27ae7 HEAD@{5}: commit: 11/05/2017 2:33pm
    3e4c616 HEAD@{6}: merge origin/master: Fast-forward
    1e79818 HEAD@{7}: commit: 10/5//2017 UI
```

I tried to do a checkout from `0f27ae7236aabbe8cccfba82e201e36368a05054` but my changes weren't back. What I want is to restore the last commit I made in (no branch) **(commit: 14/05/2017 3:33pm)**.

Here is the result of `git branch -a`:

```
$ git branch -a
* (HEAD detached from 0f27ae7)
  UI_linking
  master
  remotes/ado/newBranch
  remotes/origin/UI_linking
  remotes/origin/frogs1
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/newBranch
  remotes/origin/newMas
```

Are my changes lost? Or is there a way to recover them?

Comment: Can you show git branch -a ?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Answer (score 12):

From the output of `git reflog` I would say your changes are on commit `7b8ee7b` (`HEAD@{2}`).

The following commands:

```
git branch lost 7b8ee7b
git checkout lost
```

should create a new branch (named `lost`) on the aforementioned commit then check it out.

Then you can do:

```
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge --ff lost
```

to move the two commits you recovered on top of the `master` branch and make them appear as part of the `master` branch history.

If everything looks good then you can run `git branch -d lost` to remove the `lost` branch.

Comment: This worked great! In my case the branch was automatically removed on the merge (due to the settings I set in the repository), but I'm glad to have my edits back!

Comment: Had this issue when committing on submodules in VS Code. Your comment saved me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can restore your state doing `git checkout 7b8ee7b` where `7b8ee7b` is the hash under `HEAD@{2}` in your reflog - the one before you switched to master.

What happened: you switched from master branch to `0f27ae7236aabbe8cccfba82e201e36368a05054` for some reason and ended up in "detached head" state. You did some commits but those weren't on any branch. These commits still exist and you can see them in reflog.

While `0f27ae7236aabbe8cccfba82e201e36368a05054` is what your master points to, when you switch to hash, you don't switch to any branch that points to that commit.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is: You pushed your branch to no branch that announce some warnings but You ignored them. Now, this code is detached to HEAD.So your new modified code will be on HEAD~. You can see in the relog:

> 0f27ae7 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to 0f27ae7236aabbe8cccfba82e201e36368a05054

The way to get it back:

1. You fetch your git source:

> git fetch origin

2. Checkout to HEAD

> git checkout  remotes/origin/master

3. Finally, Merge  0f27ae7 HEAD@{1} to master

> git merge HEAD@{1}

Now, You got your code in the master.

Regards,